# Flutter Class Widget, "watch" function got an error

Tags: flutter, widget, watch

I want to make a var with watch function, but it keep getting and error this is the code :

```
class Booking extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, watch) {
    var step = watch(currentStep).state;
    var mallWatch = watch(selectedMall).state;
```

the "watch" inside the var keep getting a red underline, the error is "The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked" please help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Skimmed through [Riverpod docs](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading/#using-refwatch-to-observe-a-provider) and apparently your code should be:

```dart
class Booking extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    // not sure .state is necessary, depends on what you're trying to retrieve
    var step = ref.watch(currentStep).state;
    var mallWatch = watch(selectedMall).state;
    ...
  }
}
```